# jQuery event help - I have a Select list with OptGroups, I want to call function only if option belongs to a certain optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a select list with optgroups. I want to add a handler for the drop down selected index change, how do I tell which optgroup the selected item belongs to? This determines further execution path. I understand how to add the function, the function contents are more the issue.

```
$ddl.bind("change", function(){
  //how do I find out which option group the selected option belongs to?
  var selectList = $(this); 
});
```

Thanks for any tips.

Cheers,
~ck

Comment: I figured this out. Im using the selectbox jQuery plugin. 
                            var open = "Open";
                        var tmpInner = $(this).selectedValues()[0];
                        var group = $(this).selectedOptions().parent();
                        if (group[0].label == open) {
                            $(".addressDDL").selectOptions(tmpInner).change();
                        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="marcas">
    <optgroup label="ford">
        <option>ka</option>
        <option>fiesta</option>
        <option>mondeo</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="peugeot">
        <option>305</option>
        <option>306</option>
        <option>205</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(function(){

    $("#marcas").change(function () {
        alert($(this).find(":selected").parent().attr("label"));
    });

});
</script>
```